# How to use font-awesome in ejs file from node modules?

Tags: css, node.js, font-awesome-4

I have installed font-awesome 4.7 in my nodejs application

I have to get it in my views.ejs file.

i tried importing using  tag...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" >
```

and from css file like this...

```
@import url('../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

but they doesn't help....

It is failing to load when looking at the browser's network tab...

Please help.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/

Comment: You're almost certainly _not_ hosting your whole node_modules directory.

Comment: Try it from here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/javascript-api/setup/getting-started

Comment: You cannot do it this way. It will not work. NodeJS does not open the `node_modules` folder until you explicitly mention Express to do so which is a high security threat as it exposes your server side code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an ejs app in production that uses font awesome and I just use the CDN. But also Atheesh Thirumalairajan post is a valid way.  Just make sure you are serving from a public folder.

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c03ec31dc2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need not use `node_modules` instead, the easy way of doing it is to download Font Awesome from https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/

Then, extract the files your `public` folder (You need to define the public directory in express)

Then, In the `<head></head>` section of your HTML, add:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

You can also checkout their official [examples](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/).
The same thing applies to Font Awesome 5 But, you need to download from https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself